How many lower-case 6 letter words can I write so that every pair has exactly two matching letters?
To put it formally, how many 6-letter words with letters from 'a' to 'z' can I write, where for every pair $w_i$ and $w_j$, there are exactly two distinct indices $1\leq a, b\leq 6$ such that $w_i[a] = w_j[a]$ and $w_i[b] = w_j[b]$, and for every other index $c \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\} - \{a,b\}$, $w_i[c] \neq w_j[c]$?
I think the answer is 26, but I cannot prove we can't have more than 26 words satisfying the above condition. How should I prove it?

This sounds like a question about pure math, rather than about computer science.  Is there some aspect in which this needs to be answered from a CS perspective?

@D.W. I believe there is, but I haven't included it in the question to keep it small. The computer science aspect would be how to create the set once you know how many. I believe it's also discussed in the paper cited by pcpthm.

Such a construction is called an equidistant code in coding theory. Define $B_q(n,d)$ as the maximum number $N$ of codewords $c_1, \dots, c_N \in \{0,\dots,q-1\}^n$ with every pair having the equal Hamming distance $d(c_i,c_j) = d$, for $i \neq j$. The question asks to find the value of $B_q(n,d)$ in the case of $q = 26$, $n = 6$, and $d = 4$.
In [1], it is proven that $B_q(n,d) = \max \{16,q\}$ for all $q \geq 4$ and $5 \leq n \leq 33$ (Theorem 15). Therefore, $26$ is the maximum number of words satisfying the constraints of the question.

[1] Bogdanova, Galina T., Victor A. Zinoviev, and Todor Jordanov Todorov. "On the construction of q-ary equidistant codes." Problems of Information Transmission (2007). [pdf]

